# Is there a way to monitor when a Mac is about to go to sleep?

Tags: objective-c, macos, sleep, nsnotifications

Is there a programmatic way to monitor when a Mac is about the to go sleep? I would like to monitor when the user deliberately tells the system to go to sleep and when the system is preparing to sleep naturally.

Comment: The first hit from a [search for "sleep"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=sleep) in the Apple docs is: [Registering and unregistering for sleep and wake notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html). Have you read that? Are you stuck on some aspect of it?

Comment: @Josh, Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Please add an answer to the question and I will accept it.

Comment: My answer would only consist of that link. A better solution for posterity's sake would be for you to come back when you have implemented something and self-answer with some code and details.

Comment: @David - Otherwise, please just close the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can register for the following notification like this:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveSleepNotification:) name:NSWorkspaceScreensDidSleepNotification object:NULL];
```

You can register for a wake notification like this:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveWakeNotification:) name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification object:NULL];
```